# Draw HyperNeutrino's benzene hegaxon icon in ASCII

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, kolmogorov-complexity, geometry

In celebration of [HyperNeutrino](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/68942/hyperneutrino) getting back his account and rep, [following Mr. Xcoder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/128075/20260).

[image: HyperNeutrino's flair]

Apologies for rotating the picture for drawability.

---

Print or output this ASCII art exactly. You may have trailing spaces and/or a trailing newline.

```
      _______________
     /               \
    /  /           \  \
   /  /             \  \
  /  /               \  \
 /  /                 \  \
/  /                   \  \
\                         /
 \                       /
  \                     /
   \                   /
    \  _____________  /
     \_______________/
```

This depicts one of the two resonance structures of the molecule [benzene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benzene)
[image]

Related: [Concentric hexagons](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/37440/draw-concentric-ascii-hexagons), [asterisk-filled hexagons](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/104604/could-you-make-me-a-hexagon-please)

**Leaderboard:**

```js
var QUESTION_ID=128104,OVERRIDE_USER=20260;function answersUrl(e){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/128104/answers?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+ANSWER_FILTER}function commentUrl(e,s){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/"+s.join(";")+"/comments?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+COMMENT_FILTER}function getAnswers(){jQuery.ajax({url:answersUrl(answer_page++),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){answers.push.apply(answers,e.items),answers_hash=[],answer_ids=[],e.items.forEach(function(e){e.comments=[];var s=+e.share_link.match(/\d+/);answer_ids.push(s),answers_hash[s]=e}),e.has_more||(more_answers=!1),comment_page=1,getComments()}})}function getComments(){jQuery.ajax({url:commentUrl(comment_page++,answer_ids),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){e.items.forEach(function(e){e.owner.user_id===OVERRIDE_USER&&answers_hash[e.post_id].comments.push(e)}),e.has_more?getComments():more_answers?getAnswers():process()}})}function getAuthorName(e){return e.owner.display_name}function process(){var e=[];answers.forEach(function(s){var r=s.body;s.comments.forEach(function(e){OVERRIDE_REG.test(e.body)&&(r="<h1>"+e.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG,"")+"</h1>")});var a=r.match(SCORE_REG);a&&e.push({user:getAuthorName(s),size:+a[2],language:a[1],link:s.share_link})}),e.sort(function(e,s){var r=e.size,a=s.size;return r-a});var s={},r=1,a=null,n=1;e.forEach(function(e){e.size!=a&&(n=r),a=e.size,++r;var t=jQuery("#answer-template").html();t=t.replace("{{PLACE}}",n+".").replace("{{NAME}}",e.user).replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",e.language).replace("{{SIZE}}",e.size).replace("{{LINK}}",e.link),t=jQuery(t),jQuery("#answers").append(t);var o=e.language;/<a/.test(o)&&(o=jQuery(o).text()),s[o]=s[o]||{lang:e.language,user:e.user,size:e.size,link:e.link}});var t=[];for(var o in s)s.hasOwnProperty(o)&&t.push(s[o]);t.sort(function(e,s){return e.lang>s.lang?1:e.lang<s.lang?-1:0});for(var c=0;c<t.length;++c){var i=jQuery("#language-template").html(),o=t[c];i=i.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",o.lang).replace("{{NAME}}",o.user).replace("{{SIZE}}",o.size).replace("{{LINK}}",o.link),i=jQuery(i),jQuery("#languages").append(i)}}var ANSWER_FILTER="!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe",COMMENT_FILTER="!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk",answers=[],answers_hash,answer_ids,answer_page=1,more_answers=!0,comment_page;getAnswers();var SCORE_REG=/<h\d>\s*([^\n,]*[^\s,]),.*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/,OVERRIDE_REG=/^Override\s*header:\s*/i;
```

```css
body{text-align:left!important}#answer-list,#language-list{padding:10px;width:290px;float:left}table thead{font-weight:700}table td{padding:5px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b"> <div id="answer-list"> <h2>Leaderboard</h2> <table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="answers"> </tbody> </table> </div><div id="language-list"> <h2>Winners by Language</h2> <table class="language-list"> <thead> <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="languages"> </tbody> </table> </div><table style="display: none"> <tbody id="answer-template"> <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="language-template"> <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table>
```

Comment: I see @HyperNeutrino has since rotated his icon to match this question!

Comment: @Neil Yes :P It bothered me so much that I just changed it to make it consistent. Now you need to update the resonance structures, xnor :P

Comment: Darn, the flair won't update even though I added random unused parameters to the end, changed it to StackOverflow, changed it back, and edited another like 10 times :I

Comment: But the horizontal version looks ugly when rendered on my profile in my opinion; could just be that I'm not used to it. So, I changed it back. :P

Comment: :( I wanted to see!

Answer (score 25):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 23 bytes

```
×_⁷↙←×_⁸↖⁶→↗⁶Ｐ×_⁸↘↓↙⁵‖Ｂ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5///w9PhHjdsftc181DYBzN7xqG3ao8Ztj9omPWqbDmS837MBJj7jUdtkkMrGrY8apr3fs@j/fwA) Explanation: Prints the lines in the following order, then reflects everything horizontally:

```
      5_______
     /        
    /  6      
   /  ↙       
  /  /        
 ↗  /         
4  /          
\             
 \            
  \           
   \          
    ↖  1→_____
     3______←2
```

Comment: `‖Ｂ` stands for "Reflect Butterfly"

Answer (score 8):

### JavaScript (ES6),  <s>144</s>  <s>143</s> <s>140</s> <s>138</s> 134 bytes

A recursive function drawing the output character by character with a purely conditional expression.

```js
f=(p=363)=>(m=p%28-14,x=m<0?-m:m,y=p/28|0,p--)?`\\/ _
`[m+14?x<8-y&y<2|x<8&y>11?3:x==y+8|x==19-y|x==16-y&y>5&x>5?m<0^y>5:2:4]+f(p):''
```

#### How?

For each position **0 < p ≤ 363**, we define:

- **m = (p MOD 28) - 14**
- **x = | m |**
- **y = ⌊ p / 28    ⌋**

Below is a breakdown of the formula which picks the appropriate character from `[ '\', '/', ' ', '_', '\n' ]`.

```js
m + 14 ?                            // if this is not an end of line:
  x < 8 - y & y < 2 |               //   if this is either part D
  x < 8 & y > 11 ?                  //   or part E:
    3                               //     output '_'
  :                                 //   else:
    x == y + 8 |                    //     if this is either part A
    x == 19 - y |                   //     or part B
    x == 16 - y & y > 5 & x > 5 ?   //     or part C:
      m < 0 ^ y > 5                 //       output '/' or '\' depending on the quadrant
    :                               //     else:
      2                             //       output a space
:                                   // else:
  4                                 //   output a Line-Feed
```

And below are the different parts in the coordinate system defined above:

```
   | 13 12 11 10 09 08 07 06 05 04 03 02 01 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13
---+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
12 | .  .  .  .  .  .  E  E  E  E  E  E  E  E  E  E  E  E  E  E  E  .  .  .  .  .  .
11 | .  .  .  .  .  B  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  B  .  .  .  .  .
10 | .  .  .  .  B  .  .  C  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  C  .  .  B  .  .  .  .
09 | .  .  .  B  .  .  C  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  C  .  .  B  .  .  .
08 | .  .  B  .  .  C  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  C  .  .  B  .  .
07 | .  B  .  .  C  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  C  .  .  B  .
06 | B  .  .  C  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  C  .  .  B
05 | A  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  A
04 | .  A  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  A  .
03 | .  .  A  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  A  .  .
02 | .  .  .  A  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  A  .  .  .
01 | .  .  .  .  A  .  .  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  .  .  A  .  .  .  .
00 | .  .  .  .  .  A  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  A  .  .  .  .  .
```

#### Demo

```js
f=(p=363)=>(m=p%28-14,x=m<0?-m:m,y=p/28|0,p--)?`\\/ _
`[m+14?x<8-y&y<2|x<8&y>11?3:x==y+8|x==19-y|x==16-y&y>5&x>5?m<0^y>5:2:4]+f(p):''

o.innerHTML = f()
```

```html
<pre id=o></pre>
```

Answer (score 7):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 50 bytes

```
•ι¡≠ït]4uƵŽΣ”9g½ùöèri|)á,ćè’∍é•5B3ÝJ"/ _\"‡4¡.B».∞
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AV0Aov8wNWFiMWX//@KAos65wqHiiaDDr3RdNHXGtcW9zqPigJ05Z8K9w7nDtsOocml8KcOhLMSHw6jigJniiI3DqeKAojVCM8OdSiIvIF9cIuKAoTTCoS5Cwrsu4oie//8)

---

***The compression:***

The strategy here was to build half the object, then mirror the image across the halfway mark. To do this, I first built the left half, with front padding:

```
11111122222222
111110
11110110
1110110
110110
10110
0110
3
13
113
1113
1111311222222
11111322222222
```

But no right padding, this is because the `.B` function in 05AB1E can be used to make every element equal in length using spaces. This allows for me to omit the extraneous spaces to the right and just delimit by newlines. I then, took this pattern, and removed all newlines replacing them with `4` to get:

```
1111112222222241111104111101104111011041101104101104011043413411341113411113112222222411111322222222
```

Compressing this with base-255 results in:

```
•ι¡≠ït]4uƵŽΣ”9g½ùöèri|)á,ćè’∍é•5B
```

Where the two `•` is denoting a base-255 compressed string and 5B is converting it to base-5.

---

***The second part, after the compressing:***

```
3ÝJ                # Push '0123'.
   "/ _\"          # Push '/ _\'.
         ‡         # Replace each in b with a on c.
          4¡       # Split on 4's (the newlines I replaced).
            .B     # Boxify for the mirror (adds padding to longest element).
              »    # Join by newlines. 
               .∞  # Mirror image.
```

Comment: You could save 3 bytes like [this](https://tio.run/##AVgAp/8wNWFiMWX//yIvIF9cCiLigKLOucKh4omgw690XTR1xrXFvc6j4oCdOWfCvcO5w7bDqHJpfCnDoSzEh8Oo4oCZ4oiNw6nigKI10LLDqEouQsK7LuKInv//)

Comment: @emigna `è`, of course!

Answer (score 5):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 61 bytes

```
i/  /±¹ \  \
\²µ /6ñGÙlxxhPHÄãxx>ñv$r_jwr w.Gkkl13r_jviwr_jd
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/P1NfQUH/0MZDOxViFBRiuGIObTq0VUFf2uzwRvfDM3MqKjICPA63HF5cUWF3eGOZSlF8VnmRQrmee3Z2jqExkFeWWQ4kU/7/BwA)

Hexdump:

```
00000000: 692f 2020 2fb1 b920 5c20 205c 0a5c b2b5  i/  /.. \  \.\..
00000010: 202f 1b36 f147 d96c 7878 6850 48c4 e378   /.6.G.lxxhPH..x
00000020: 783e f176 2472 5f6a 7772 2077 2e47 6b6b  x>.v$r_jwr w.Gkk
00000030: 6c31 3372 5f6a 7669 7772 5f6a 64         l13r_jviwr_jd
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>226</s> <s>213 bytes</s> 179 bytes

My first golf!

```python
b,f,s,u='\/ _'
print'\n'.join([s*6+u*15,s*5+f+s*15+b]+[s*(4-n)+'/ /'+s*(13+2*n)+'\ \\'for n in range(5)]+[s*n+b+s*(25-2*n)+f for n in 0,1,2,3]+[s*4+b+s*2+u*13+s*2+f,s*5+b+u*15+f])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY7BDoIwEETvfsXetnQXkUK9@SXWGJtYxcNCKBz8@gp78DZ5eZOZ6bu8R3GlRE6ceb1gaOCOh2keZMEgePyMg5hrtmdabes5W0@J8hYp3mjjpq@lImygwQ2btiNndxAgBEzjDAKDwPyQ19P4SitCcVedr1VN8NdO3LLjTq1eLbfPdhqSjkf9QelWlfID)

I tried looping the bits that I could find a pattern on, and hardcoded the rest. Setting the different characters to a variable helped save quite a lot of bytes.

Edit: Decided to append to the same array instead of joining multiple times. Saved 13 bytes.

Edit 2: Thanks to @ValueInk, @jacoblaw, @WheatWizard, @CalculatorFeline, and @Challenger5, saved 34 bytes

Comment: You can do p=print if you want to do this in python 3, [saves 2 byte](https://tio.run/##Zc5NDoIwFATgPaforj@vQEDqwoaTWGNoYhVjXhsKC09fS93pbib5kpnwXh8eDylZ6WSUm/RyGqkxutVEX3VLSKsNIcbQJobXvDKqKa/CGJYZ1yowapA2Tz8jO0dxhE10SkahwEHMEeyF88r5hSCZkSwT3m9M8VNgUbChRg4@O9Z10Itcpj87fC2C3V2v6uIc/10eCuj3/UMJrryw5RC4/CKlDw)

Comment: Looks like you commented while I was making an edit :). No need for multiple print statements now

Comment: `b,f,s,u='\/ _';o,a='/  /','\  \\'` saves 11 bytes over your current variable initialization! [See here](https://tio.run/##Xc7BDsIgDAbgO0/RWxlFl@HwticRY0YiOg9lge3g0@OG8eLtb/slf@f38oxsSvE66KzXAV0LNxRRjwO2AC1qdADOoUjDJaszraqzOitLgfIWyV9Fov0k@wM3FLet7DoyahtGCDEBw8SQRn7cpW1@msnv0thDleFf9l@ZVV@h2XtPNYTa7usjFMScJl7QMR5fcWKZmlI@ "Python 2 – Try It Online")

Comment: using @ValueInk's tip and not making a list over 4 lines, you have [195 byte like this](https://tio.run/##Xc7BDoIwDAbgu0/RW8c6JEzmxfAkjhiWOMVDRxgcfPo5Fr14@9t@yd/5vT4D65Sc8iqqrUfbwA0vQY09NtCgQgvW4mFeJl7RMh5fYWJxjfJMm2yNitKQp5gjuQEI8kV0NVcU8lK0J9IyDyP4sADDxLCM/LgLU30xk9uhNnWB/h92P9gVqPfWUwm@dLvyBvmhSukD)

Comment: @jacoblaw You don't need all the spaces in that. [Here](https://tio.run/##Xc5BDoIwEAXQvaeY3ZROkVCoG8NJLDE0sYqLKaGw8PS11J27Pz8v@bN8tldgnZJTXkW1D2gbuOM1qGnABhpUaMFaPC3rzBtaxvM7zCxuUV5ol61RURryFHMkN1LuRV9zRSFXou1Iy3xM4MMKDDPDOvHzIUxVKJM7mDZ1Yf6f9T/WF6aPva4EX1ZdeYD8WKX0BQ "Python 2 – Try It Online") it is without them.

Comment: `o` and `a` are only used once in the code. [Here it is with them inlined.](https://tio.run/##XY7BDsIgEETvfsXelrLUprT05pdIYyQRrYelgfbg12PBm7fJy5vMrJ/tFVjn7JRXSe0XtB3c8LTGhTe0jOd3WFhck5xol71RSRrylI5IbqaDi7HlhrCDDg8s@oG0LMCCtehDBIaFId75@RCmqRUmV1Rt2qp6@NPGnzZWTZfdoQZf1109Qn5ucv4C "Python 2 – Try It Online")

Comment: You can use `0,1,2,3` instead of `range(4)` to save a byte.

Answer (score 4):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>129</s> <s>114</s> 102 bytes

*Thanks to ovs for -12 bytes!*

```
6eea¶5/15\¶4c1b3c3b2c5b1c7bc9b\25d1\23d2\21d3\19d4\2ee_2d5\eea/
e
aa
d
/¶
c
/2/1
b
\2\¶
a
___
\d+
$*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Dcy7DcMwDAXA/k3hIpVdCKSsBN6FgMBfkSZFkNk0gBZTPMDdN3/vj66FZ6bO0Qo1meN0surV2JuRv8wvE25BwjVYmKIKXXEKZ3aOJrctSKgiUOaAo3AhGITvDYreOyQOPPZtrT8)

Comment: [101 bytes](https://tio.run/##DcwrDkIxEEZh/68CgQLRzPQWcvcySTMvgUEQFAvrArqxUnnEdz75fb11LTwydY5WqMkch5NVr8bejPxpfloLqsEUVeiMQzizczTZqiChikCZA47ChWAQ3h8oeu/47YLEHdfbZa0/ "Retina – Try It Online")

Answer (score 4):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <strike>47 43</strike> 41 bytes

```
↗⁶Ｆ¹⁵_↓↘⁶←↙⁶↷⁴↑Ｆ¹⁵_↖⁶Ｍ⁴→↗⁵Ｍ¹¹→↓↘⁵Ｍ⁵↙↑Ｆ¹³_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5//9R2/RHjdve71l2aOejxq3xj9omP2qbARR51DbhUdtMMGP7o8Ytj9omIqmZBtayFiw@CWzCViD30E6gPIgPMWIrWMVWkClQzYc2x///DwA)

I did not know a thing about Charcoal until right now, I felt like "I have no idea of what I'm doing" while trying to figure out this answer... I'm quite sure this can be golfed a lot.

Updates:

- I managed to save 4 bytes learning to use cursor directions and movements!
- 2 more bytes saved after realizing the drawing was not exactly as asked. ^__^U

Comment: Lmao, trust me, you're not the only one to be in [the latter state](http://imgur.com/dzbQCj4) when using charcoal. The first time I used it was trying to make a cube. I used the "square" built-in then manually drew the back of the cuboid, turns out you can do it in 20 bytes compared to my 57.

Comment: @carusocomputing I cannot believe that O5AB1E or Jelly still have longer answers... :-D

Comment: Charcoal is an extremely competitive ASCII-oriented language, the optimized answer is likely around 40 bytes which may even obliterate bubblegum.

Comment: @carusocomputing *cough* did you say 40?

Comment: @Neil I did try to use `‖Ｂ` but I could not figure out how... nice answer!

Comment: ;) I knew itd be you too haha.

Answer (score 4):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 155 bytes

```
('_ /\',LF){~5#.inv 95x#.32-~3 u:'0_C5NcBe''e2kA/jhk>5y~l<Z:AN<QG)V7m>l"x!@A-jp8E%XEh&"$''j(sP8Z!b#e7})]_,L"LCUu)kqsBQ5_5bt}`bq ":1cv(gU;|{I~n5q@(ISCK `'[<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcYLC8FQGIDhv/I5w7dT24x1wiyZhWTJJZJL09YyG2MNTTh/fXjrqTfMfS@4AFEAAf@BxEEF/UdWwJpJdj8X0YHKFn9LX5wJyjF@QJNlgqLVZK7BXUfVsdjY6/qIfi0yK2EQtdmTn4y1bo6N6YAu6@f2iWSFjimH10avtOoFZVJEDMV00lgXXMGvf@jOkWxiW4s7jZK0O2UOc2@fvZsA0aveQzwsWu/XkMcs6YjDuTWCPW6MnOZf)

This is a function that expects no input. E.g., `f =: <code>` then `f ''`.

### Explanation

I encoded this using the following steps. Assume that the desired compression string is contained in the variable `h`.

```
   k=:'_ /\',LF                    NB. the dictionary used to encode the string
   k i. h                          NB. numbers corresponding to indices in `k`
1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 4 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 3 4 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 3 1 1 3 4 1 1 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 3 1 1 3 4 1 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 3 1 1 3 4 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 ...
   5x#.k i. h                      NB. base 5 to decimal
4571656960356964266407389291886526966074643634545109498506871241033015964671946641835339522170115810676380078148856766959449166714046433431522704650346045752930168245684048485736756807881102718244115576453623363843561553955078139
   95#.inv 5x#.k i. h              NB. decimal to base 95
16 63 35 21 46 67 34 69 7 69 18 75 33 15 74 72 75 30 21 89 94 76 28 58 26 33 46 28 49 39 9 54 23 77 30 76 2 88 1 32 33 13 74 80 24 37 5 56 37 72 6 2 4 7 74 8 83 48 24 58 1 66 3 69 23 93 9 61 63 12 44 2 44 35 53 85 9 75 81 83 34 49 21 63 21 66 84 93 64 66 8...
   quote u:32+95#.inv 5x#.k i. h   NB. base 95 to ASCII repr of string
'0_C5NcBe''e2kA/jhk>5y~ll"x!@A-jp8E%XEh&"$''j(sP8Z!b#e7})]_,L"LCUu)kqsBQ5_5bt}`bq ":1cv(gU;|{I~n5q@(ISCK `'
```

Then, we just need to decode this. `5#.inv 95x#.32-~3 u:` performs the inverse of what I just described, giving us the list of indices. Then, `('_ /\',LF){~` applies the appropriate characters to each index.

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica, 227 bytes

```
t=Table;T[x_,y_,z_,v_]:=""<>{x,y~t~v,z};Column[Join[b={""<>"_"~t~15},{T["/"," ","\\",15]},t[T["/  /"," ","\\  \\",i],{i,11,19,2}],t[T["\\"," ","/",i],{i,25,19,-2}],{T["\\  ","_","  /",13]},{""<>{"\\",b,"/"}}],Alignment->Center]
```

Answer (score 4):

## Ruby, 117 bytes

```
13.times{|i|s=[?_*(15--i%12*1.3),"/%#{i*2+8}s"%?\\,''][(i%12%11+3)/5].center(27)
i>0&&(s[i-=7]=?\\)&&s[~i]=?/
puts s}
```

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>92</s> <s>86</s> 80 bytes

```
'_15×6ú'/5úð8×«.∞5F'/4N-ú'/2ú«ð6N+×«.∞}4F'\Núð13N-×«.∞}'\4ú'_7×2ú«.∞'\5ú'_8×«.∞»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f9fPd7Q9PB0s8O71PVND@86vMHi8PRDq/UedcwzdVPXN/HTBUkYHd51aPXhDWZ@2jDJWhM39Rg/kHpDY6AamKh6jAlQfbz54elgLSAx9RhTkBDc2EO7////mpevm5yYnJEKAA)

---

### Explanation in parts

The bar at the top

```
'_      # underscore
  15×   # repeated 15 times
     6ú # with 6 spaces in front
```

The line immediately below the bar

```
'/         # forward slash
  5ú       # with 5 spaces in front
    ð      # space
     8×    # repeated 8 times
       «   # concatenated with the earlier string
        .∞ # intersected mirror (i.e middle space not affected)
           # mirroring: "  /  " => "  /    \  "
```

The remainder of the upper portion of the hexagon

```
5F                     # for N in 0..4
  '/                   # forward slash
    4N-                # 4 - N
       ú               # spaces in front of the slash
        '/             # another forward slash
          2ú           # with 2 spaces in front
            «          # concatenated with the other string
             ð         # a space character
              6N+      # N + 6
                 ×     # times
                  «    # concatenated with the other string
                   .∞  # intersected mirror
                     } # end for
```

The remainder except for the last 2 lines

```
4F               # for N in 0 .. 3
  '\             # backslash
    Nú           # with N spaces in front 
      ð          # a space
       13N-      # 13 - N
           ×     # repeated
            «    # concatenated with other string
             .∞  # intersected mirror
               } # end for
```

The second to last line

```
'\ # backslash
  4ú # with 4 spaces in front
    '_ # underscore
      7× # repeated 7 times
        2ú # with 2 spaces in front
          « # concatenated with earlier string
           .∞ # intersected mirror
```

The last line

```
'\ # backslash
  5ú # with 5 spaces in front
    '_ # underscore
      8× # repeated 8 times
        « # concatenated with other string
         .∞ # intersected mirror
```

The `»` at the end joins everything on newlines.

Comment: @carusocomputing: hmm, I didn't think of "mirroring" it.

Comment: Mirror is like palindromize, except with palindromize `{_` becomes `{_{`, where with mirror it becomes `{_}`. Palendromize is `û`, while mirror is `∞`. There is also an intersected mirror, which is `.∞`.

Comment: @downvoter stoppit. He said he's still golfing it.

Answer (score 3):

## C#, <strike>210</strike> 199 bytes

Encodes the length of space runs and underscore runs:

```
var h=@"5KL4/>\L3/1/:\1\L2/1/<\1\L1/1/>\1\L0/1/@\1\L/1/B\1\L\H/L0\F/L1\D/L2\B/L3\1I1/L4\K/L";for(var i='M';--i>'/';)h=h.Replace(""+i,i>75?"\n":"".PadLeft(i>72?i-60:i-47," _"[i/73]));Console.Write(h);
```

Ungolfed:

```
var h = @"5KL4/>\L3/1/:\1\L2/1/<\1\L1/1/>\1\L0/1/@\1\L/1/B\1\L\H/L0\F/L1\D/L2\B/L3\1I1/L4\K/L";
for (var i = 'M'; --i > '/'; )
    h = h.Replace("" + i, i > 75 ? "\n" : "".PadLeft(i > 72 ? i - 60 : i - 47, " _"[i / 73]));
Console.Write(h);
```

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##Fc1Ba4MwGMbxrxJyMWHV16idYKYt3RgbTaFshx6aMYJN5wtOh3GFUfrZnTn9fzyXp3Zh3Q92@nXYfZH3Pzfab1m3xjmyv7rRjFiTS48nsjPYMX6dLmYgTbmmy63KoNIqBQGFFlolMx48xIzKI56x9pi78dUvoGL9DEroJ1CJ3oBKtXgVoDK9BUXluR@YP8Ay2AUyDLEKIJC8KZvozf60praM0jtcYJUvV1R3tKA02puTsueRzWOywvA@LjDM8gUln/SIkKcfnMvHvnN9a6PDgKNlDZfT7Tb9Aw)

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 129 bytes

```
5$* ¶    
\G (?=( *))
¶$1/  /$`11$* $`\  \
r`(?<=( *)) \G
$1\$'19$* $'/¶
^
6$* 15$*_¶5$* /15$* \
¶$
¶    \  13$*_  /¶5$* \15$*_/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY0xDgIxDAR7v2ILS5e7xrIQSEigK@8TFoSCgobixNvygHwsbC6uVtrZ8f7@fb6v1uSsC2oBT2JDWu8JyzxLLeoGmGZ3EpoDCNlzWm@DQGyiHjr5tfeT1SIPuTA7lc9auth65o42GU@o8RN7qgcSB26t/QE) Completely different approach, yet coincidentally the same length!

Answer (score 2):

## [Paintbrush](https://github.com/alexander-liao/paintbrush), 43 bytes, non-competing

```
13→'_8×←↓s/5{↙s/3→s/3←}↓'\6×↘↑'_8×→↖'_7×←▕┣
```

#### Explanation

```
13→'_8×←↓s/5{↙s/3→s/3←}↓'\6×↘↑'_8×→↖'_7×←▕┣  Program
13→                                          Move the pointer 13 spaces right
   '_                                        Push '_' onto the stack
     8×                                      Multiply it 8 times
       ←                                     Draw out '________' moving to the left
        ↓                                    Move down
         s/                                  Set that cell to a slash
           5{         }                      Execute function 5 times
             ↙                               Move the pointer one spot down and one spot to the left
              s/                             Set that cell to a slash
                3→                           Move 3 spaces right
                  s/                         Set that cell to a slash
                    3←                       Move 3 spaces left
                      ↓                      Move down
                       '\                    Push r'\'
                         6×                  Multiply it 6 times
                           ↘                 Draw out r'\\\\\\' moving down-right
                            ↑                Move up
                             '_              Push '_'
                               8×            Multiply it 8 times
                                 →           Draw out '________' moving to the right
                                   ↖         Move the pointer one spot up and one spot to the right
                                    '_       Push '_'
                                      7×     Multiply it 7 times
                                        ←▕┣  Draw out '_______' moving to the left
                                         ▕   Remove the rightmost column
                                          ┣  Mirror the entire grid to the right, overlapping the inner column, flipping some characters that have backwards variants
```

Beta Testing in the Real World:

```
Charcoal: 1
Paintbrush: 0
```

Gotta make a lot of improvements, huh. :P

Comment: And user themself posts a solution!

Comment: @ValueInk It's about time, huh? :P

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 122 bytes

```php
<?=gzinflate(base64_decode("ddDBDQAgCEPRO1N0AxYicf8tFK2JIPT4HycA34iTHRVxJqwvGLvme8LXrxRAKoVmBZypoMNFjbmUtMEl/OV2WHqYTg"));
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt42vSozLy0nsSRVIymxONXMJD4lNTk/JVVDKSXFxckl0DHd2TUgyN/Qz8CxIjIzOc2ixM3byMszIMTEozLZ0dgkM8QjKKzCq7C8zN2nLDfVwieiqCLI0Ts/LNcpqrIg39fPLSspN7TE1zVH3z/MKNyjMDIkXUlT0/r//695@brJickZqQA)

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 158 bytes

```php
for(;~$c='f000
e/o1d/b/k\b1c/b/m\b1b/b/o\b1a/b/q\b1/b/s\b1\y/
a\w/
b\u/
c\s/
d\b00___b/
e\000/'[$i++];)echo$c>_?str_pad("",ord($c)^96):strtr($c,[_____,"\
"]);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcxBCoMwEAXQ/RwjBDQYmLgptLb1II4NJlGUUpJGS@mmV7fTWfzH/4tJc9rPbeKcYi6br/SXYjLGwIixDujwTq727IN1bGQH9skyK0MfhIHeCI5eCJ5WhEDOGGutQxiJ32HRyaWq@kaNfo7SX227btmmIZRC6JhDKb26HQ/qxPOWuenO/k8LAtGrZt9/)

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 165 bytes

```php
<?=strtr("5566666
57/3334
5 13552513352713332 13355 213335 2433335 0 433355 0743333054333505 476666_ 057466666/",[" /
","/  /","\  \
","     ","\\","   ",___,"  "]);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYwxDsIwFEP3nsL6E0hFSfNjMgDiIBRFqELqBFXp1ZlDfvBg@3nwMi@lnK@Xz7Zu607Io6ljcqoaO2JQMnBQZUjVNcA6EQxqRG3pYaXuPrXFs7EnYrLHDM8U27mT/iZwnfTigEoyAqMhTMbjH6TPOVuT@/5Uyvf1PkyPaX7@AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////), 152 bytes

```
/,/  //'/\\!!!//&/\\"\\
//%/\/"\/!!//#/_____//"/,\\//!/,, /! ###
!\/!!!\\
,"% \& "% "&"%!\& \%!"&\%!,"&\'!!\/
 \'! "/
"'! \/
 "',"/
,"\,##___"/
!\\###\/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FU07CkMxDNtzClsmyWLQhQSlQ6FDt3d/UsWDPkaWn9/7@X6ec9iMIDelzCSXBaRBTooQ77L4ukOCLZHJ7mBGVY28kfRFY4ZWGLEw01IzsQxt3M5whDnAAdO12G3XUFf5gbWb3Cqe8wc)

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>58</s> 55 bytes

```
'/__\ '7XyP9BY+3l7:14&(6Xy_3TF_5M&(&v0'Zj'(t2&P_h)[]9Z(
```

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/X10/Pj5GQd08ojLA0ilS2zjH3MrQRE3DLKIy3jjELd7UV01DrcxAPSpLXaPESC0gPkMzOtYySuP/fwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 111 bytes

```
J\/K\\+*6d*15\_+++*5dJ*15dKV5+++*-5hNd"/  /"*+yN11d+++KddK)V4+++*NdK*-25yNdJ)+++++*4dK*2d*13\_*2dJ+++*5dK*15\_J
```

This code basically prints the lines one after another (in the naive way of doing it). Yeah it sucks, but right now I'm in no state of doing better, and I too still wanted to pay tribute to [HyperNeutrino](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/281362).

[Try it online!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=J%5C%2FK%5C%5C%2B%2A6d%2A15%5C_%2B%2B%2B%2A5dJ%2A15dKV5%2B%2B%2B%2A-5hNd%22%2F%20%20%2F%22%2A%2ByN11d%2B%2B%2BKddK%29V4%2B%2B%2B%2ANdK%2A-25yNdJ%29%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2A4dK%2A2d%2A13%5C_%2A2dJ%2B%2B%2B%2A5dK%2A15%5C_J&debug=0)

Answer (score 1):

## [Bubblegum](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Bubblegum), <s>67</s> 54 bytes

```
00000000: 55c9 310d 0040 0804 c1fe 55e0 0043 24f8  U.1..@....U..C$.
00000010: 77f1 c955 cc96 3b95 d65e 6697 4d76 0b93  w..U..;..^f.Mv..
00000020: cf06 f847 0448 d1e6 0ceb 5722 8421 1010  ...G.H....W".!..
00000030: d95b 7e60 ad3f                           .[~`.?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY67DkFBFEV7X7GJ@uTMe4aCREGjFIVEmJeG8tL59Ws8O6vcJ3udHbsYz@XUXfqeP0xgTApQgjOYNYM9ayRRSzsUfmYKUlcPbEgQzamxIVqMafA2iOZwrgqkYAxSChYqBoNsTYG1wUFnZ8ExKOD2Kk@J9pXWV/o6ZHOkyhbVawfW2iOL0kqpRBgnJbyWAqI9A9qAJa2eO7YjGv4cqjlyMBGuWMYxq4r/0O5@oFnfPwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [SOGL V0.12](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL), <s>53</s> 52 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
/↕Υ¦‛¾}`¼Pσ↕ΗΦ▒∙⌠N►4┼ΥjΠ⌡jOT?»m,┌∆Χ⁶↑┌≠Γ‽‼║%Ν□‘7«n╬⁷
```

[Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=LyV1MjE5NSV1MDNBNSVBNiV1MjAxQiVCRSU3RCU2MCVCQ1AldTAzQzMldTIxOTUldTAzOTcldTAzQTYldTI1OTIldTIyMTkldTIzMjBOJXUyNUJBNCV1MjUzQyV1MDNBNWoldTAzQTAldTIzMjFqT1QlM0YlQkJtJTJDJXUyNTBDJXUyMjA2JXUwM0E3JXUyMDc2JXUyMTkxJXUyNTBDJXUyMjYwJXUwMzkzJXUyMDNEJXUyMDNDJXUyNTUxJTI1JXUwMzlEJXUyNUExJXUyMDE4NyVBQm4ldTI1NkMldTIwNzc_)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 187 bytes

```python
a=`int("7YSUQZDJS0I3J2QJ40G9WNPIRBTBC1KF0F3X5WDMBW8CG5BVDHBJQ71V3UHCSY3TR8LC4IIEE5SZ",36)`[:-1]
for i in"0666666_!6__!5/!3\\!9\n!844!422!211!1 ".split("!"):a=a.replace(i[0],i[1:])
print a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Hc7JCoJAGADge0/hP6eEltk0E7yMtmgLmZqZig1RNBAm1qWnt@h7gq/5vO/PmnaddM6qfvfRJIuS8OQFEfZZQMOA48U03e78vYiFS1ZzPGdHI/U2IrXchSEO3lIE4YQcWLJ0o4zFe2vtct@fzYzohAbM1M@5PSRl7/ZsNaWpGmHzrwKzqsAYAysKmBY1WJwDpxQoIUA0NHo1D/X7ANJt6chRe20e8nLtqxyXA5UTu9R7Tfsra7Lrvg)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>154</s> 138 bytes

```python
print'eNp10MEJAEEIA8C/VaSDNBTY/rtYlByci+aZER8BMqcnqiR6FG7/IPd87w0c/pQMYBrFJmxhQDstljJSQUrb5euhZzBe6PI3aQ=='.decode('base64').decode('zip')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PcjNCoIwAADgx1kSNPtTLx5czlBQnFagtzkHLkznXJS@/Lr1HT@56G4cDsZIJQYNeCb3doqTAOM48C7wQcswQ7cKKl31aGFiS2tceCid2DCJwomuLozz1nM/NoOSpBVSUfL6diScdf9MSnJXzZm/u3pF3MnjIyW@D3YtZ2PLN6ChM3dOwPrHKiSwjPkB)

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 169 bytes

```cs
var d=new char[364];for(int i=10;i-->0;)for(int j="ppnggffggn"[i]-97;j-->0;)d[28*"amlhbccbha"[i]+"ggh{fguva|"[i]-2813+j*("b|~}"[i/3]-97)]="_/\\\n"[i/3];Console.Write(d);
```

Ungolfed:

```cs
var d = new char[364];
for (int i = 10; i-- > 0; )
    for (int j = "ppnggffggn"[i] - 97; j-- > 0; )
        d[28 * "amlhbccbha"[i] + "ggh{fguva|"[i] - 2813 + j * ("b|~}"[i / 3] - 97)] = "_/\\\n"[i / 3];
Console.Write(d);
```

For each stroke I encoded the start position, length, character used, and direction within various strings. I saved a few bytes by grouping up similar strokes.

Sadly, this prints a little weird in tio. This is because I'm not printing out real spaces. Looks fine in my console, though. So probably this submission doesn't count. Here's the link anyways.

[Try it online! (fake spaces 169 bytes)](https://tio.run/##NczNC4IwHMbxf2XspIaVGb0w7NI5CDp0UIk55/yJbbJNI8z@dXuj6@f58jDjM6X52BqQAp3uxvIrYTU1Bh17Y6kFhjoFOTpQkI7bjx3VKI8kvyFWUh2Hq2VKCqUdkBZBFMwJ@P5uTty/VRFuGilEUQghcQypv12T6tfk8WLjYXqty4yxrKSfeYKFKPtCtB19fPPFJggnlefg7PEc3jILPxduGuHLLEkS@SOyV9Komk/PGix3cpeMwzC@AA)

[Try it online! (real spaces 191 bytes)](https://tio.run/##NYxda8IwGEb/yktuTHT1q7I5QgfD68FAYRdWRpqm6VtqIknskFr/eucH3p7nnEf6SFqn@qNHo2F98kHtuayF9/Dd@iACSmgs5vAl0FDW9o1wkEMCRv3BOrhrRQcweIlfF2y8satSuE/nxIkyXlhH0QTAZDblGEUfU86erErI4WC0LgqtDdniLnp/49XDybfz5ZCIfV1mUmaluM0jonXZFvrYiPNdny9n8agaUpKdL92VTOLbBdsl5HeSpql5IL6yxttajX8cBkVzxvuu6/8B)

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 200 bytes

```c
char o[28];i,j,k,p;f(){for(k=0;k<39;puts(o))for(memset(o,k&&k<32?32:95,27),i=3;i--;k++)for(j=3;j--;o[24-i*3+j]=" _\\/"[p])o[i*3+2-j]=" _/\\"[p="U@@@B@HH@``@@BB@HH@``@@p@@L@@C@p@EL@UC@"[k]-64>>j*2&3];}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY/NCsIwEITP9ilKDyWxCUrif6wuiuDBq6c2aClVk1BTbD0Vn71GBU8z8@0yMDm95nnX5bfs4duEzaRQRBNDKnFBuL3YBzLxUJgln4vq2dTIYvyBZVHWRYMsMWHojmzN2WI@JmyKiYq5UJQKE0XfV@2ydtm1j6jq80jLOPBPaToIkkpim3wYoz86SFNH4@AIABvY7@F8dubvKoADwNbp7gDHLQSJkXQyWq10n4Vcilen7o1fZuqOsNd6PbdBeK/uDQ)

Answer (score 0):

## [Deadfish~](https://github.com/TryItOnline/deadfish-), 872 bytes

```
{iii}iicccccc{iiiiii}iii{c}ccccc{{d}ii}dddddc{ii}iiccccc{i}iiiiic{d}ddddd{c}ccccc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iicccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddcc{i}iiiiic{d}ddddd{c}c{iiiiii}c{dddddd}cc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iiccc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddcc{i}iiiiic{d}ddddd{c}ccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}cc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iicc{i}iiiiic{d}dddddcc{i}iiiiic{d}ddddd{c}ccccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}cc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{ii}iic{i}iiiiic{d}dddddcc{i}iiiiic{d}ddddd{c}ccccccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}cc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{iiii}dddc{d}dddddcc{i}iiiiic{d}ddddd{c}ccccccccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}cc{iiiiii}c{{d}ii}ddc{{i}dd}iic{dddddd}{c}{c}ccccc{i}iiiiic{dddd}iiic{ii}iic{iiiiii}c{dddddd}{c}{c}ccc{i}iiiiic{dddd}iiic{ii}iicc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}{c}{c}c{i}iiiiic{dddd}iiic{ii}iiccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}{c}ccccccccc{i}iiiiic{dddd}iiic{ii}iicccc{iiiiii}c{dddddd}cc{iiiiii}iii{c}ccc{dddddd}dddcc{i}iiiiic{dddd}iiic{ii}iiccccc{iiiiii}ciii{c}ccccc{ddddd}iic
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZPRDoAgCEW/qI9qUovnHpnfTooKTtOpLw655yxywnXCje9zMBMiekQnKxapRnI@HRGE0kNcsV@yJKlQhL40FcgOIyusowYik8gR@Ll3Ves2xeveTfOOeEOdLmpNuqyluMlH51hw2NDqBwmhTdjIlRozQ2iC/DLViGNwNr8@gNJq/2ZvM139eiAnHfMH)

Answer (score 0):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 45 bytes

```
»R√UǏ8x⟑9↓ḋSŀ«+Ġ↵‡⊍6-}h≥kẇ⊍ḣW£»`/ _\,`τ⌐øŀ⁋øM
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLCu1LiiJpVx484eOKfkTnihpPhuItTxYDCqyvEoOKGteKAoeKKjTYtfWjiiaVr4bqH4oqN4bijV8KjwrtgLyBfXFwsYM+E4oyQw7jFgOKBi8O4TSIsIiIsIiJd)